# Attempted import error: 'path-to-regexp' does not contain a default export (imported as 'pathToRegexp')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Failed to compile the react-router. This happend after installing path-to-regexp

> ./node_modules/react-router/esm/react-router.js

```
Attempted import error: 'path-to-regexp' does not contain a default export (imported as 'pathToRegexp').
```

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of downgrading to an old version, just change the way you import: from:

```
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
```

to

```
import { pathToRegexp } from 'path-to-regexp';
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, this occurred as my path-to-regex had been updated to newer version.

I solved this by simply reverting back to the old version of path-to-regex.To do that simply run this:
`npm i path-to-regexp@2.4.0 --save`

Comment: Is reverting to an old version really a good solution? I've added the way to fix this with the current version of path-to-regex in another Answer.